# what are the requirements for netctl wifi-menu in arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, netctl

I wanted to setup wifi on my arch linux machine with `wifi-menu` But it doesn't connect to wifi. It shows no error and it says, that im connected to the internet. But with `ping 8.8.8.8` I get `Network is unreachable`. Am i missing packets or firmware for my wifi card? btw my wifi card driver is `atk10-pci`. Can someone help?

Comment: Edit: My wifi card is working properly. Maybe i am missing packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed packages: dhcpcd, wireless_tools, wpa_supplicant, netctl, dialog and dhclient